# Symbol for anamorphism

Tags: math-operators

Are there LaTeX symbols for the 'lens brackets' representing an 'anamorphism', as per page 4 of ['Functional Programming with Bananas, Lenses, Envelopes and Barbed Wire](https://maartenfokkinga.github.io/utwente/mmf91m.pdf)?

The `stmaryrd` package has symbols for 'banana brackets' (catamorphisms):
(`\llparenthesis`, `\rrparenthesis`) and 'envelope brackets' (hylomorphisms) (`\llbracket`, `\rrbracket`).

However, I can't find anything for anamorphisms.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The paper uses square brackets and parentheses, with a rather poor result.

Here's a better one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\newcommand{\lbparen}{%
  \mathopen{%
    \sbox0{$()$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0}%
    \raisebox{-\dp0}{%
      \begin{picture}(.32,1)
      \linethickness{\fontdimen8\textfont3}
      \roundcap
      \put(0,0){\raisebox{\depth}{$($}}
      \polyline(0.32,0)(0,0)(0,1)(0.32,1)
      \end{picture}%
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\rbparen}{%
  \mathclose{%
    \sbox0{$()$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0}%
    \raisebox{-\dp0}{%
      \begin{picture}(.32,1)
      \linethickness{\fontdimen8\textfont3}
      \roundcap
      \put(-0.08,0){\raisebox{\depth}{$)$}}
      \polyline(0,0)(0.32,0)(0.32,1)(0,1)
      \end{picture}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\lbparen g,p\rbparen$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need to use the Euler fonts, some values need to be changed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\newcommand{\lbparen}{%
  \mathopen{%
    \sbox0{$()$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0}%
    \raisebox{-\dp0}{%
      \begin{picture}(.3,1)
      \linethickness{\fontdimen8\textfont3}
      \roundcap
      \put(0,0){\raisebox{\depth}{$($}}
      \polyline(0.3,0.07)(0,0.07)(0,0.98)(0.3,0.98)
      \end{picture}%
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\rbparen}{%
  \mathclose{%
    \sbox0{$()$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0}%
    \raisebox{-\dp0}{%
      \begin{picture}(.3,1)
      \linethickness{\fontdimen8\textfont3}
      \roundcap
      \put(-0.08,0){\raisebox{\depth}{$)$}}
      \polyline(0,0.07)(0.3,0.07)(0.3,0.98)(0,0.98)
      \end{picture}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\lbparen g,p\rbparen$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing!! From where `.32` come?

Comment: @Sigur Trial and error

Comment: are these in the stix fonts?  (i can't check.)  i think they are, which means they would also have unicodes.  that would be useful information.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I can't find them

Comment: @egreg -- thanks.  i'll star this for investigation when i get access to my usual system again.  will probably be a few weeks.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm not sure these symbols are used anywhere else, but they're not unreasonable delimiters.

Comment: @egreg -- i know i've seen them, just have to remember where.  i think they're in a japanese context, which makes me think they did make it into stix.  but if japanese, already in unicode, so they wouldn't have gotten new codes.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Bingo! U+3016 and U+3017. They are in all TeX Gyre Math fonts (including Latin Modern Math) and Cambria Math, but not STIX.

Answer (score 4):

The solution which does not need LaTeX picture environment is here. Only `\vrule` and `\hrule` primitives are used. But this solution does not care about script and scriptscript sizes. But egreg's solution does not care about it too.

```
\def\lbparen{\mathopen{\vrule \lower.249em\vbox to1em{%
   \hrule height.2pt width.3em\vss \hrule height.2pt}%
   \kern-.32em(}}
\def\rbparen{\mathclose{)\kern-.32em\lower.249em\vbox to1em{%
   \hrule height.2pt width.3em\vss \hrule height.2pt}%
   \vrule}}

$\lbparen g, p\rbparen$

\bye
```