# How do you typeset "banana" brackets?

Tags: brackets

I'm looking to place an equation between so called "banana" brackets, that look like the ones in [this question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/11356).

How can I do that?

Comment: Special case of [symbols - Double square brackets - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107252/double-square-brackets/107464#107464)

Comment: Your question is answered in this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408066/symbol-for-anamorphism: Use `\llparenthesis` and `\rrparenthesis` from the `stmaryrd` package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility using `stix`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}

\[
\llparenthesis x \rrparenthesis
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also `\left\lParen \frac{a}{b} \right\rParen`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'd love to see your approach as an answer!

Comment: Just add it to yours.  It was your idea to use stix.